# What does the numbers after the reputation score mean?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

What do the numbers after the rep score mean? Like the 1 and 7 here: [image: Like in the image here]

Comment: Have you hovered over them?

Comment: And now knowing about hovering: that is useful for many details. Like: hover "xx minutes", hover the vote buttons, hover user names in comments, ...!

Comment: I hadn't! Agreed with @Arjan, so many things to hover over now

Comment: My comment was not a complaint, @CambridgeMike ;-)

Answer (score 5):

They're badges

If you hover over them, you'll see "1 silver badge" or "7 bronze badges".

> [As you use Stack Overflow to ask and answer questions, you’ll earn badges, which appear on your user page and in your user card.](https://stackoverflow.com/badges)

Comment: The hover doesn't appear to work anymore and I had the same question.  Thanks!

Comment: @Tom it does for me